# Uber iOS SDK Support at the time of Ride and after Ride

Tags: ios, uber-api

I have developed an application using Uber iOS SDK (https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk). In that, I have used below things as Uber support (Ride Requests - Buttons) within our app.

- Login
- Start and Destination Selection
- Choose Uber Products (Auto or Car)
- The cost and estimated time
- Request for ride

Here my doubt is, Is Uber SDK support available at the time of ride and after ride ? like **Ride Track** and **Payment Process**.

Is there any document or proof available for that ?

Or am I need to check this in a real ride ?

**Note**: *The sandbox mode is not working in Uber setup within our app. So I couldn't check this in developer mode*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the uber sdk before, during, and after the ride. In most cases you will want to use a server-side sdk to handle after the trip is completed. Take a look at docs on how to use webhook to listen to different states of the rides: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/webhooks

See the available client libraries: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/sdks